# numpy vectorize if elif elif else

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, vectorization, boolean-expression

I have a function:

```py
def aspect_good(angle: float, planet1_good: bool, planet2_good: bool):
    """
    Decides if the angle represents a good aspect.
    NOTE: returns None if the angle doesn't represent an aspect.
    """

    if 112 <= angle <= 128 or 52 <= angle <= 68:
        return True
    elif 174 <= angle <= 186 or 84 <= angle <= 96:
        return False
    elif 0 <= angle <= 8 and planet1_good and planet2_good:
        return True
    elif 0 <= angle <= 6:
        return False
    else:
        return None
```

I want to vectorize it, such that instead of passing one value for each argument I could pass in numpy arrays. The signature would look like this:

```py
def aspect_good(
    angles: np.ndarray[float],
    planet1_good: np.ndarray[bool],
    planet2_good: np.ndarray[bool],
) -> np.array[bool | None]:
```

I'm not sure how to do it though, I could convert each if, elif statement:

```py
((112 <= angles) & (angles <= 128)) | ((52 <= angles) & (angles <= 68))
((174 <= angles) & (angles <= 186)) | ((84 <= angles) & (angles <= 96))
((0 <= angles) & (angles <= 8)) & planets1_good & planets2_good
((0 <= angles) & (angles <= 6))
# how to convert the 'else' statement?
```

But I'm not really sure how to connect them now. Can somebody please help? I don't have a lot of experience with numpy, maybe it has some useful functions to do this.

**UPDATE**

Big thanks to everybody, and especially to `@Mad Physicist`.

So, I can use this:

```py
def aspect_good(angles: np.typing.ArrayLike, planets1_good: np.typing.ArrayLike, planets2_good: np.typing.ArrayLike) -> np.typing.NDArray:
    """
    Decides if the angle represents a good aspect.
    """
    result = np.full_like(angle, -1, dtype=np.int8)

    false_mask = np.abs(angle % 90) <= 6
    result[false_mask] = 0

    true_mask = np.abs(angle % 60) <= 8
    result[true_mask] = 1

    return result
```

This is awesome! Kudos to Mad Physicist, the solution is *so* beautiful and simple, even simpler than what I had before.
Have a happy life, good sir!

Comment: I want to return an `np.array` of True, False, None.

Comment: You'll have to think what returning None means. Is it indicative of an error? Then raise an exception (ValueError probably). Should it perhaps also be False instead? Or is it indicative of "don't know, don't care"? Then use a masked array, and mask the None elements.

Comment: @9769953 returning `None` doesn't mean an error, nor does it mean `False`. There is a clear distinction between `False` and `None` in my app, as it says in the function docs "None means the angle is nor good nor bad"

Comment: Aaah. The ole' three -state boolean problem

Comment: Would "invalid" be a good indication for those elements in the array that ends up in the else branch?

Comment: A `bool` dtype array can only have True/False values.  An integer one could have more.  Object dtype could contain the `None` values (in fact `np.empty(3, object)` returns an array full of `None`).  But you can't do further logic on an array containing `None`.  A `np.ma` masked array could mark some values as "not valid".  That in effect uses 2 bool arrays, the `data` and the `mask` (valid/invalid).

Comment: @9769953 I wouldn't call them invalid, it's just some angles are good, some are bad, and some are neither. All angles are valid. I need 3 states. But I'm starting to understand the problem, now that `hpaulj` explained it. Maybe marking the None angles as invalid would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To code this in numpy, you will need to adjust your thinking in a couple of ways.

The biggest is vectorization. You can't have `if` statements processing each element individually and still be efficient, so you'll need to convert the logic to something more streamlined.

The other point is that you can't have a three-value boolean. That means that you'll either have to redefine your conditions to fit into a true-false dichotomy, or use a different datatype. I'm going to show the latter approach with integers valued `0` for False, `1` for True, and `-1` for None.

Each condition looks at angle, and I see only one range collision. I would recommend the following approach:

- Make an output array filled with None values (-1)
- Figure out which values to set to False, and do it
- Figure out which values to set to True, and do it

The order here is important, because you want True values to supersede the False ones when `angle <= 6` but both planets are good.

```
def aspect_good(angle: np.typing.ArrayLike, planet1_good: np.typing.ArrayLike, planet2_good: np.typing.ArrayLike) -> np.typing.NDArray:
    """
    Decides if the angle represents a good aspect.
    NOTE: returns None if the angle doesn't represent an aspect.
    """
    result = np.full_like(angle, -1, dtype=np.int8)

    false_mask = ((174 <= angle) & (angle <= 186)) | ((84 <= angle) & (angle <= 96)) | ((0 <= angle) & (angle <= 6))
    result[false_mask] = 0

    true_mask = ((112 <= angle) & (angle <= 128)) | ((52 <= angle) & (angle <= 68)) | ((0 <= angle) & (angle <= 8) & planet1_good & planet2_good)
    result[true_mask] = 1

    return result
```

Those extra parentheses are important: unlike logical operators, bitwise operators have tighter binding than comparison operators.

This function doesn't care if you pass in a multi-dimensional array or a scalar for `planet*_good`. All that matters is that the three inputs broadcast against each other.

You can recast the range conditions as a distance from the midpoint:

```
false_mask = (np.abs(angle - 180) <= 6) | (np.abs(angle - 90) <= 6) | (np.abs(angle - 3) <= 3)
```

Out of curiosity, did you mean to use the following simplification?

```
false_mask = np.abs(angle % 90) <= 6
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! You are very smart. I am very lucky to have such a good solution from you. Everything broken down and presented well, and you even found some ways to improve my conditions.

Comment: Regarding the range conditions, I have updated my question, you were right.

Comment: Is there a way I could thank you? I can probably award you a bounty, but I'm not sure if you even care about reputation at this point...

Comment: @acmpo6ou I'm glad to be of help. There's no need to go beyond an upvote and selecting the answer. I'm not quite done caring about reputation just yet: ~500pts to go until I get swag :) That being said, just knowing that I've helped to show you how to think numpythonically is enough. I'll sleep well knowing that there's one less person trying to use np.vectorize for everything

Comment: 500pts for you? That's as much as I have! I can do it! But I can award you a bounty only after 2 days, and by that time you might not need me anymore (because you would get there yourself). And I want to contribute the final drop that will overflow your reputation! What do you think? How many reputation a day do you get?

Comment: `np.vectorize`?! I new there would be something like this! But it's good I didn't, otherwise I wouldn't have met you.

Comment: @acmpo6ou. No bounties please. I'm probably going to get the remaining 100pts today regardless. And I really mean it about setting you on the right path being reward enough.

Comment: @acmpo6ou. np.vectorize is the bane of experienced numpy users :) please don't use it. It's basically a hidden `for` loop, created by the original authors to confuse and mislead the unsuspecting beginner. You're much better off learning to think in terms of vectorized pipelines if you want to use numpy effectively

Comment: Oh that's sad for me, but in advance congrats! Also, did you get 400pts during the last half an hour?! That's sick!

Comment: Oh, OK. I won't abuse np.vectorize then, and will learn a proper way. Thank you for the pointer! Man, I want to shake your hand so badly.

Comment: @acmpo6ou. Nothing that drastic. I have 85 points today, most of them from passive income. I just didn't estimate my reputation correctly :)

Comment: Consider this to be a virtual handshake. I'm always happy to meet people that are trying to learn and not just dumping their homework here and acting entitled.

Comment: Handshake excepted , thanks! True, I understand.

Comment: Hey, Mad Physicist, I have updated the question. Maybe you could help me some more? If you have the time and want to. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @acmpo6ou. I suggest asking a separate question instead of tacking on additional, unrelated, information to an existing question. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, I was also thinking about that. My question became very long and kinda ugly. I will start a new question then. Thanks!

Comment: @acmpo6ou. I suggest you remove everything starting with at least Update 1.

Comment: I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73708238/11004423