# How to debug numpy masks

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, vectorization, masking

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73672739/11004423).

I have a function that I'm trying to vectorize. This is the original function:

```py
def aspect_good(angle: float, planet1_good: bool, planet2_good: bool):
    """
    Decides if the angle represents a good aspect.
    NOTE: returns None if the angle doesn't represent an aspect.
    """

    if 112 <= angle <= 128 or 52 <= angle <= 68:
        return True
    elif 174 <= angle <= 186 or 84 <= angle <= 96:
        return False
    elif 0 <= angle <= 8 and planet1_good and planet2_good:
        return True
    elif 0 <= angle <= 6:
        return False
    else:
        return None
```

and this is what I have so far:

```py
def aspects_good(
    angles: npt.ArrayLike,
    planets1_good: npt.ArrayLike,
    planets2_good: npt.ArrayLike,
) -> npt.NDArray:
    """
    Decides if the angles represent good aspects.

    Note: this function was contributed by Mad Physicist. Thank you.
    https://stackoverflow.com/q/73672739/11004423

    :returns: an array with values as follows:
        1 – the angle is a good aspect
        0 – the angle is a bad aspect
       -1 – the angle doesn't represent an aspect
    """
    result = np.full_like(angles, -1, dtype=np.int8)

    bad_mask = np.abs(angles % 90) <= 6
    result[bad_mask] = 0

    good_mask = (np.abs(angles - 120) <= 8) |\
                (np.abs(angles - 60) <= 8) |\
                ((np.abs(angles - 4) <= 4) & planets1_good & planets2_good)
    result[good_mask] = 1

    return result
```

It's not working as expected, however, I wrote a test with pytest:

```py
def test_aspects_good():
    tests = np.array([
        [120, True, False, True],
        [60, True, False, True],
        [180, True, False, False],
        [90, True, False, False],

        [129, True, False, -1],
        [111, True, False, -1],
        [69, True, False, -1],
        [51, True, False, -1],
        [187, True, False, -1],
        [173, True, False, -1],
        [97, True, False, -1],
        [83, True, False, -1],

        [0, True, True, True],
        [0, True, False, False],
        [0, False, True, False],
        [0, False, False, False],

        [7, False, False, -1],
        [7, True, True, True],
        [9, True, True, -1],
    ])

    angles = tests[:, 0]
    planets1_good = tests[:, 1]
    planets2_good = tests[:, 2]
    expected = tests[:, 3]

    result = aspects_good(angles, planets1_good, planets2_good)
    assert np.array_equal(result, expected)
```

and it fails, saying False, the arrays are different.

Here I have `result` and `expected` arrays combined side by side:

```py
array([[ 1,  1],
│      [ 1,  1],
│      [ 0,  0],
│      [ 0,  0],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [ 0,  1],
│      [ 0,  0],
│      [ 0,  0],
│      [ 0,  0],
│      [-1, -1],
│      [-1,  1],
│      [-1, -1]])
```

Note: the first column is `result` array, and the second one is `expected`. As you can see, they differ in two places. Now the question comes "How to debug this?" Normally I would use a debugger, and step through each if/elif/else condition. But I have no idea how to debug numpy masks.

Comment: Typically I create a simple example that embodies all the alternatives.  By keeping it small, I can print the arrays, and even some intermediate ones, and from that determine what's wrong.  It's so easy to throw some prints in python code, that I rarely resort to using the debugger.

Comment: Did you forget a return value?

Comment: Minor nitpick, but arrays are conventionally initialized with lists instead of tuples. Couple of reasons: 1) it looks more like MATLAB, 2) tuples are used to initialize structured arrays, so this can lead to confusion.

Comment: I see a difference in the second-to-last case. Reduce your example to just those inputs (scalars), and decide (a) if the function is wrong or your expectation is a typo, and (b) if the function is wrong, how to fix it.

Comment: Also the 13th case (index 14). So maybe reduce to those two, or process them one at a time. The logic is simple enough that you can do it by hand even.

Comment: For reference, `(0, True, True, True)` and `(7, True, True, True)` are the problem rows. Are you sure that the function you pasted here is the same one you're running?

Comment: Ooooh. This one is actually subtle. Glad I tried it before I voted to close

Comment: @hpaulj. I would not necessarily expect a beginner to catch this particular issue by themselves the first time. I know I've made the mistake of attempting to use an integer array as a mask before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be a combination of three things:

1. Numpy uses a homogeneous type throughout an array.

   You will find that `tests.dtype` is `dtype('int64')` or `dtype('int32')` depending on your architecture. This means that the columns containing `planet1_good` and `planet2_good` are integers too, not booleans.
2. Bitwise AND (`&`) is *not* a logical operator.

   A bitwise AND operation will return a result with the largest of the input types. Specifically for the result of `<=`, which *is* a boolean, and an `int` array, the result will be an `int`. That means that you can do something like `np.array([1, 2]) & np.array([True, True])` to get `array([1, 0])`, **not** `array([True, False])`.
3. Numpy distinguishes between a boolean mask and a fancy index by the dtype, even if the fancy index contains only zeros and ones. If you have a 2 element array, `x`, then `x[[True, True]] = 1` assigns `1` to both elements of `x`. However, `x[[1, 1]] = 1` assigns `1` only to the second element of `x`.

So that's basically what's happening here. `bad_mask` is a boolean mask, and works exactly as you would expect. However, `good_mask` ANDs with a couple of integer arrays, so becomes an integer array containing zeros and ones. The expression `result[good_mask] = 1` is actually assigning the first and second element of `result` to be `1`, which fortuitously correspond to two of your tests. The remaining `True` results can not and will not be assigned `1`.

There are a few ways to fix this, listed in decreasing order of preference (my favorite on top):

1. Convert all your arrays to numpy arrays of the correct type. Right now your function does not meet the contract that it accepts any array-like. If you pass in a list for `angles`, you will get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'`. This is a fairly idiomatic approach:

   ```
   angles = np.asanyarray(angles)
   planets1_good = np.asanyarray(planets1_good, dtype=bool)
   planets2_good = np.asanyarray(planets2_good, dtype=bool)

   result = np.full_like(angles, -1, dtype=np.int8)

   bad_mask = np.abs(angles % 90) <= 6
   result[bad_mask] = 0

   good_mask = (np.abs(angles - 120) <= 8) |\
               (np.abs(angles - 60) <= 8) |\
               ((np.abs(angles - 4) <= 4) & planets1_good & planets2_good)
   result[good_mask] = 1
   return result
   ```
2. Ensure that `good_mask` is actually a mask before applying it. You should still convert `angles`, but the other arrays will be converted automatically by the `&` operator:

   ```
   good_mask = ((np.abs(angles - 120) <= 8) |\
                (np.abs(angles - 60) <= 8) |\
                ((np.abs(angles - 4) <= 4) & planets1_good & planets2_good)).astype(bool)
   ```

   You may alternatively do something similar to what you did with `bad_mask`:

   ```
   good_mask = (np.abs(angles % 60) <= 8) & (angles >= -8) & (angles <= 128)
   ```
3. Convert the mask to an index, which won't care about the original dtype:

   ```
   result[np.flatnonzero(good_mask)] = 1
   ```

Comment: Wow, you found the issue! Again! Thank you! I will take a look at it later, right now I have to go to work, that's why I'm not as active on this question as I would want to be.

Comment: Also, congrats with reaching 100k rep. I hope you'll get some great swag :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the 1st solution, and it's working. You explained everything very well, and I understood what the problem was. It wasn't working because I wasn't masking the array, I was fancy indexing it. It's very nice that you and others help me learn, I like the project I'm working on right now very much. It presents a lot of very interesting challenges like optimizing everything with vectorization.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 2nd solution though. The part where you're saying "You may alternatively do something similar to what you did with bad_mask". I have tried the code, but my test is failing. Also, I don't understand how it works, I understand this code `(np.abs(angles % 60) <= 8)`, but not this `(angles >= -8) & (angles <= 128)`. Shouldn't we use `planets*_good` somewhere there?